# WinForms - Binding ListBoxControl

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, devexpress

I'm trying to bind List to ListBoxControl (Devexpress).
Everything is fine except DisplayMember attribute.
I see that the list is bind (I can move throught 3 list position using mouse, or keyboard).
The problem is that there is no text in the controls.

```
public partial class ExportXml : XtraForm
{
    private List<Xml> _listXml;

    public ExportXml()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadWindows();
    }

    private void LoadWindows()
    {
        _listXml = new List<Xml>
        {
            new Xml{Id = 1, Name1="xml1", Name2="xml11"},
            new Xml{Id = 2, Name1="xml1", Name2="xml22"},
            new Xml{Id = 3, Name1="xml1", Name2="xml22"}
        };
        _listBoxControl.DataSource = _listXml;
        _listBoxControl.DisplayMember = "Name1";
        _listBoxControl.ValueMember = "Id";
    }
}

public class Xml
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name1;
    public string Name2;
}
```

[print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR531.png)

Answer (score 3):

To accomplish this task, replace your custom class' public fields with corresponding public properties.

Comment: Shame on me :(
Thanks, I forgot about Xml class at all